# How to print sorted by the number of points? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

results.txt

```
Alan: 15 points.
Smith: 10 points.
Luka: 20 points.
```

expected print:

```
Luka: 20 points.
Alan: 15 points.
Smith: 10 points.
```

Code:

```
def print_results():

    with open("results.txt", "r") as f:
        linija=f.readlines()

    linija=sorted(linija,key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)

    print("######### HALL OF FAME #########\n")
    for line in linija:
        print line
    print("################################")
```

Need help, how to get those points and sort by them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each line when you read it, then sort by the `int` value in the resulting list. Then, print out the output using `' '.join` to get it back as a string

```
with open("results.txt", "r") as f:
    linija=[i.split() for i in f.readlines()]

linija = sorted(linija,key=lambda x: int(x[1]),reverse=True)

print("######### HALL OF FAME #########\n")
for line in linija:
    print(' '.join(line))
print("################################")
```

Output:

```
######### HALL OF FAME #########

Luka: 20 points.
Alan: 15 points.
Smith: 10 points.
################################
```

Comment: You could save some effort using `linija = sorted(linija,key=lambda x: int(x.split()[1]),reverse=True)`